# Find posterior distribution of Gaussian likelihood with Gaussian prior

Tags: integration, statistics, bayesian

Let $\beta$ be a $p\times 1$ vector, $Y$ a $p\times 1$ vector, and $X$ a $n\times p$ matrix. Suppose we have the following density functions
$$f(\beta) = \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{p/2} \lambda^{-p}} \exp\left(-\frac{\lambda}{2} \beta^T \beta \right)$$
$$f(Y\mid \beta ) =\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{n/2}} \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}(Y-X\beta)^T(Y-X\beta)\right)$$

How can I find $f(Y) = f(Y\mid \beta) f(\beta)$? By definition we have

$$f(Y) = \int_{\Theta} f(Y\mid \beta) f(\beta) \,d\beta $$

But this $p$-dimensional integral seems difficult to evaluate.

Comment: Not really.  For given $Y$, complete the square (in $\beta$) in the exponent of $f(Y|\beta)f(\beta)$ and ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For conjugate families, you rarely have to compute $f_{Y}(y)$. Note that
\begin{align*}
 f(\beta|y) 
 &\propto f(\beta)f(y|\beta) \\
 &\propto \exp(-2^{-1}\lambda \beta^{T}\beta)\exp(-2^{-1}(y-x\beta)^{T}(y-x\beta)) \\
 &= \exp(-2^{-1}(\lambda \beta^{T}\beta + y^{T}y -2y^{T}x\beta+(x\beta)^{T}x\beta)) \\
 &\propto \exp(2^{-1}(\lambda\beta^{T}\beta-2y^{T}x\beta + \beta^{T}(x^{T}x)\beta)) \\
 &= \exp(2^{-1}(\beta^{T}(\lambda I + x^{T}x)\beta -2y^{T}x\beta))
\end{align*}
Also note that,
\begin{align*}
 \exp(-2^{-1}(\beta-\mu)^{T}\Sigma^{-1}(\beta-\mu))
 &= \exp(2^{-1}(\beta^{T}\Sigma^{-1}\beta-2\mu^{T}\Sigma^{-1}\beta+\mu^{T}\Sigma^{-1}\mu)) \\
 &\propto  \exp(2^{-1}(\beta^{T}\Sigma^{-1}\beta-2\mu^{T}\Sigma^{-1}\beta)) 
\end{align*}
Therefore, by taking $(\lambda I+x^{t}x)=\Sigma^{-1}$ and $y^{T}x = \mu\Sigma^{-1}$, conclude that
\begin{align*}
 f(\beta|y) 
 &\propto \exp(2^{-1}(\beta^{T}\Sigma^{-1}\beta-2\mu^{T}\Sigma^{-1}\beta))
\end{align*}
That is, $\beta|Y \sim N(\mu,\Sigma)$. From the definitions, obtain that $\Sigma=(\lambda I + x^{t}x)^{-1}$ and $\mu=y^{t}x(\lambda I + x^{t}x)^{-1}$.
In case you are also after $f(y)$, note that
\begin{align*}
 f(\beta|y) &= \frac{f(\beta)f(y|\beta)}{f(y)} \\
 f(y) &= \frac{f(\beta)f(y|\beta)}{f(\beta|y)}
\end{align*}
Since we obtained $f(\beta|y)$, and $f(\beta)$ and $f(\beta|y)$ are given, you obtain $f(y)$.

Comment: So what is $f_Y (y)$?

Comment: You actually want $f_{Y}(y)$? The title of the questions says you are after the posterior. In any case, I added $f(y)$ to the answer.